# How to integrate google analytics to Titanium mobile applications?

Tags: google-analytics-api, appcelerator-titanium

I need to integrate google analytics to both iOS and Android mobile applications using Titanium. Can someone guide me on what APIs to be used and explain what values I can retrieve through them?

Comment: [this](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/5081?2051927176&restoreSearch=true#!overview) is a module present at marketplace, i think it will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Ishara,
I would start at [gitt.io](http://gitt.io/search?q=google%20analytics). It's a site dedicated to providing open-source titanium modules and widgets. This link takes you to 30 available modules. Email the developer if you have questions. Hope this helps.